# SQL Merge failing when I try to update my primary table

Tags: sql-server

I created this MERGE statement that takes data from Temp and puts it into the Word table. Here's the schema for Temp:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Temp] (
    [Word] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [SFI]  REAL          NULL,
    [U]    INT           NULL,
    [D]    REAL          NULL
);
```

Here is the MERGE:

```
MERGE [dbo].[Word] as target
USING [dbo].[Temp] as source
ON target.[WordId] = source.[Word]
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET [NAWL963SFI] = source.[SFI], [NAWL963U] = source.[U], [NAWL963D] = source.[D]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT ([WordId],[NAWL963SFI],[NAWL963U], [NAWL963D], [NAWL963]) 
    VALUES (source.[Word],source.[SFI],source.[U], source.[D], 1);
```

When it runs it gives me an error saying "

```
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 41
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'WordId', table 'ab.dbo.Word'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I checked and there are no nulls in Temp

```
 SELECT count(*) from Temp where Word = null;
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could debug this or is there something wrong with the way I am doing the merge?

Comment: Can you post schema of 'Word' table? It appears WordID column doesn't allow NULL value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you didn't search for `NULL`'s correctly, a column will never be equal to `NULL` , you have to use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` to check if a column is null :

```
 SELECT count(*) from Temp where Word is null;
```

Try chaning this row

```
USING [dbo].[Temp] as source
```

To this:

```
USING (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Temp] where [dbo].[Temp].word is not null) source
```